# How to launch a Kotlin coroutine in a `suspend fun` that uses the current parent Scope?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

How can I launch a coroutine from a suspend function and have it use the current Scope? (so that the Scope doesn't end until the launched coroutine also ends)

I'd like to write something like the following –

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    go()
}

suspend fun go() {
    launch {
        println("go!")
    }
}
```

But this has a syntax error: "Unresolved Reference: launch". It seems `launch` must be run in one of the following ways –

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    println("Go!")
}
```

Or

```
runBlocking {
    launch {
        println("Go!")
    }
}
```

Or

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    launch {
        println("Go!")
    }
}
```

Or

```
coroutineScope {
    launch {
        println("Go!")
    }
}
```

None of these alternatives does what I need. Either the code "blocks" instead of "spawning", or it spawns but the parent scope won't wait for its completion before the parent scope itself ends.

I need it to "spawn" (launch) in the current parent coroutine scope, and that parent scope should wait for the spawned coroutine to finish before it ends itself.

I expected that a simple `launch` inside a `suspend fun` would be valid and use its parent scope.

I'm using `Kotlin 1.3` and `cotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should make the function `go` an extension function of `CoroutineScope`:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    go()
    go()
    go()
    println("End")
}

fun CoroutineScope.go() = launch {
    println("go!")
}
```

Read this [article](https://medium.com/@elizarov/explicit-concurrency-67a8e8fd9b25) to understand why it is not a good idea to start in a `suspend` functions other coroutines without creating a new `coroutineScope{}`.

The convention is: In a `suspend` functions call other `suspend` functions and create a new `CoroutineScope`, if you need to start parallel coroutines. The result is, that the coroutine  will only return, when all newly started coroutines have finished (structured concurrency).

On the other side, if you need to start new coroutines without knowing the scope, You create an extensions function of `CoroutineScope`, which itself it not `suspendable`. Now the caller can decide which scope should be used.

Answer (score 10):

I believe I found a solution, which is `with(CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)`. The following example illustrates this –

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    go()
    go()
    go()
    println("End")
}

suspend fun go() {
//  GlobalScope.launch {                     // spawns, but doesn't use parent scope
//  runBlocking {                            // blocks
//  withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {       // blocks
//  coroutineScope {                         // blocks
    with(CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)) { // spawns and uses parent scope!
        launch {
            delay(2000L)
            println("Go!")
        }
    }
}
```

However, Rene posted a much better solution above.

Comment: This works, but it's kind of backwards. It uses the global `suspend val coroutineContext` and instantiates a `CoroutineScope` with it. Why don't you declare `suspend fun CoroutineScope.go()`, which is the recommended way? Also, are you sure you need `go()` to be a `suspend fun`? It doesn't actually suspend.

Comment: Making it `fun CoroutineScope.go()` is cleaner, and no, it doesn't need to be a `suspend fun`. I'm just getting my head around Kotlin's coroutines, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Say you are dealing with some RxJava Observable and it isn't the time to refactor them, you can now get a hold of a suspend function's CoroutineScope this way:

```
suspend fun yourExtraordinarySuspendFunction() = coroutineScope {
    val innerScope = this // i.e. coroutineScope
    legacyRxJavaUggh.subscribe { somePayloadFromRxJava ->
        innerScope.launch {
            // TODO your extraordinary work
        }
    }
}
```